# PHP - putcsv by specific column

Tags: php

I want to putcsv by specific column for example:

```
$fp = fopen("testing.csv", 'w');
//this is the header
fputcsv($fp, array("title","price","image1","image2","image3","shipping1","shipping2"));
//this is what i want to put
fputcsv($fp, array("title" => "test title","price" => "90","image1" => "test.jpg","image2","image3","shipping1" => "forex","shipping2"));
//and then set another null (like image2,images3, and shipping2)
```

Comment: `fputcsv($fp, array("title" => "test title","price" => "90","image1" => "test.jpg","image2" => null,"image3" => null,"shipping1" => "forex","shipping2" => null));`
`

Comment: @Mark Baker its not help, i want image2,image3,shipping2 set null automatic if i not set it.

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own function to do so, because if you don't specify a key when building an array in PHP, it treats what you have as the value and assigns a key internally

Comment: Write a function lke `function buildMyArray($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $values = array_values($array);
    foreach($keys as $index => $key) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $keys[$index] = $values[$index];
            $values[$index] = null;
        }
    }
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}
` and then call it like `fputcsv($fp, buildMyArray(array("title" => "test title","price" => "90","image1" => "test.jpg","image2","image3","shipping1" => "forex","shipping2")));`

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$fp = fopen("testing.csv", 'w');
    //this is the header
    fputcsv($fp, array("title","price","image1","image2","image3","shipping1","shipping2"));

// skeleton array with empty strings
$skeletonArr = array("title" => "","price"=> "","image1"=> "","image2"=> "","image3"=> "","shipping1"=> "","shipping2"=> "");
//merge the entries with the skeleton to keep the order, apply array_values on the resulting array
fputcsv($fp, array_values(array_merge($skeletonArr, array("title"=>"test title","price"=>"90", "image1"=>"test.jpg", "shipping1"=>"forex"))));
```

Comment: I edited my answer, you can take another look. another edit to transform assoc array to array

Comment: thank for helping me, it still manual way, the problem i have 1000 data anda some times  image2, image3 has value, and shipping2 too some time has value too.

Comment: you give me correct answer but if i still save "image2"=>"" it same the manual way, please tell me some fast way and i dont have to set if null.

Comment: ah, that was an oversight. you can just omit the null values. I adjusted the code in my answer